# How to break a single polyline into multiple polylines in ArcMap 10

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcmap

I want to delete certain segments in a selected segment of a line in a line shapefile in ArcMap 10.

Answer (score 3):

Splitting lines is generally performed using the editor toolbar, which will also allow you to delete unwanted segments once they are split.

Depending on the nature of your data there are a number of ways to split a line, outlined here in the [ArcGIS documentation](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//001t0000002z000000.htm), such as:

- At intersections
- At a specified distance along the line
- Manually
- Into equal parts

Answer (score 3):

If you have an advanced license, make use of [Feature Vertices To Points](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00170000003p000000) on your input line feature class. Next, perform a [Split Line At Point](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00170000003w000000), using your line feature class as the input feature class, and the feature vertices as your point feature class. This method will create a new feature class that contains a feature for each segment of each feature in the input feature class.

Answer (score 2):

start editing from editor. use split tool in editor to create a vertex where you hope to break the line. Then click the segment you want to delete with edit tool(a black arrow icon), and hit delete key.

Answer (score 2):

In the Editing toolbar, hit

Editor -> More Editing Tools -> Advanced Editing

Select your multipart feature, and click "Explode Multipart Feature".

This splits your multi-line feature fairly intelligently, creating independent features in the same class (make sure to create a copy before exploding if you want to preserve the original).

[image: Advanced Editing Toolbar]

[ArcGIS Help - Separating a multipart feature (Explode)](http://help.arcgis.com/en%20/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//001t0000007p000000.htm)

Answer (score 1):

ESRI calls this operation [Multipart To Singlepart (Data Management)](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00170000003r000000).  From there, simply open an edit session and delete unwanted polyline segments.

Answer (score 1):

There's a tool in the Advanced/ArcEditor level of Arcgis (works on 10.1 at least) called 
[Split Line at vertices](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00170000003p000000)to could help you, should you have this level of licence.

*"Creates a feature class containing lines that are generated by splitting input lines or polygon boundaries at their vertices."*

[image: Example]

Answer (score -1):

Densify (Editing)
Title  Densify (Editing)
Summary

Adds vertices along line or polygon features. Also replaces curve segments (Bezier, circular arcs, and elliptical arcs) with line segments.

Illustration
The curve is densified into linear segments by either the Offset, Distance, or Angle
Usage

This tool modifies the input data. See Tools with no outputs for more information and strategies to avoid undesired data changes.

Straight line segments are densified by the Distance parameter. Curve segments are simplified through densification by either the Distance , Maximum Deflection Angle, or Maximum Offset Deviation parameter.

Densification is done segment by segment.

Only one densification method can be selected each time Densify is executed.

The Spatial Reference of the data is very important to the result generated by this tool. Data should be densified in an appropriate coordinate system to maintain the correct shape of the features.

For each vertex of the original feature, including the start and end point, there will be a coincident vertex in the resulting feature.

When densifying by Maximum Offset Deviation, if the input geometry contains circular arcs, then an upper limit on the offset will be enforced such that the angle between two consecutive line segments in the output cannot exceed ten degrees. This angle can be exceeded if you densify by the Maximum Deflection Angle.

Comment: This appears to have been copy/pasted from the ArcGIS documentation without attribution, or explanation about why it is relevant to this question.